# Redirect to Welcome page in asp.net mvc4 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have an asp.net mvc4 website and I want to redirect visitors to a welcome page instead of the Home/Index default homepage. I want this page to fire only once per session i.e until the browser is closed and reopened. Upon redirection to the welcome page I want it to redirect back to the homepage after 10 seconds and the users can also click a button to redirect manually. Please how do i achieve this? Someone help!!

Comment: I think it's better to do it in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the redirect:

1. First of all store in your session whether user visited welcome page or not.
2. Then in your home index action check for this value and if it is false then return `RedirectToAction` to you Welcome page.
3. Inside your welcome page action update your session to 'remember' that user visited this page.

Regarding the redirect back to homepage:

You can achieve it by adding some javasctipt to your view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"
  }, 10000);
})
```

For manual redirect simply add a button or a link and bind it's click event to redirect function (similar to the one i wrote inside `setTimeout`).